# SQL Server Pivot - Can't add by column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't usually use pivot tables and fixing a stored procedure. I think the issue is the pivot statement.

I have the following table:

```
#status_totals
ProductName  Orders Status
-------------------------------
Product1     1      inprogress
Product1     1      inprogress
Product1     1      ordered
Product1     1      ordered
Product1     1      inprogress
```

This is the sql statement I am using.

```
select ProductName, ordered
from #status_totals
pivot (SUM(Orders) for Status in ([ordered])) as StatusTotals
```

This is the outcome

```
ProductName  ordered    
---------------------
Product1     NULL       
Product1     NULL       
Product1     1          
Product1     1          
Product1     NULL
```

This is not what I am looking for. I should have one line

```
ProductName  ordered    
---------------------
Product1     2
```

Not sure how to get the outcome I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use condition aggregate function, 
 `CASE WHEN` with `sum` to do pivot.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  ProductName varchar(50),
  Orders int,
  Status varchar(50)
);



INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Product1',1,'inprogress');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Product1',1,'inprogress');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Product1',1,'ordered');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Product1',1,'ordered');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Product1',1,'inprogress');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ProductName  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'ordered' THEN Orders END) ordered
FROM T
GROUP BY ProductName
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70398c/2/0)**:

```
| ProductName | ordered |
|-------------|---------|
|    Product1 |       2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unnecessary to use `PIVOT` for this, you should use a simple `CASE` expression and `SUM`:

```
SELECT ProductName, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'ordered' THEN Orders END) Ordered
FROM #status_totals
GROUP BY ProductName;
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix that pivot? 
Then it would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT ProductName, Orders, Status
    FROM #status_totals
    WHERE Status IN ('ordered')
) AS src
PIVOT 
(
   SUM(Orders) FOR Status IN ([ordered])
) AS pvt;
```

But to get that expected result?
This should already be sufficient:

```
SELECT ProductName, SUM(Orders) AS [ordered]
FROM #status_totals
WHERE Status = 'ordered'
GROUP BY ProductName
ORDER BY ProductName;
```